# IpOverUsbSvc error Windows Phone Developer Registration

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

When I try to register my windows phone device with **Windows Phone Developer Registration** 
I get **'unable to connect to a phone'**.

The message also says 'For Windows Phone 8 phones make sure that the Windows phone IP Over USB Transport (**`IpOverUsbSvc`**) service is running.

I followed the instructions on this site and this service is running. I still get the same problem.

What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes, restarting the phone o the trick. Also try to stop/start the IpOverUsbSvc service.

Hope this helps!

Comment: All the cool kids are switching their device off and on, thanks for the advice

Comment: Switching on and off the device always help. Thanks for the Answer.

Comment: doesn't work, and why isn't it explained where loOverUsbSvc is??