# Exception from HRESULT 0x89721200 Application Deployment tool

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I am suffering from a problem trying to open the Application Deployment tool. It always gives me this error when I try to open the program:

> Exception from HRESULT 0x89721200

PS: The Windows Phone developer registration cannot find my device and shows the 
***IpOverUsbSvc*** error.

How do I fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your operating system display language, your SDK and windows Phone must have the same language.

Second, check: Are the date and time set correctly on the phone? In SETTINGS | date + time, turn off the *Set automatically* setting and then retry registration.

If the registration succeeds, and you have a certificate error or anything wrong then download the [Preview for Developers](http://www.windowsphone.com/fr-fr/store/app/preview-for-developers/178ac8a1-6519-4a0b-960c-038393741e96?signin=true) in your phone and unlock it.

Answer (score 2):

This error can occur when the SDK's language is different to your system's language format. Try changing your system's language or else reinstalling the SDK with the same language.

Comment: Thank you very much it works 
but please do have any solution about this Problem [ipoverusbsvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19781870/ipoverusbsvc-error-windows-phone-developer-registration/19786729?noredirect=1#19786729)